# SUM of the logical array

Tags: microsoft-excel

how to sum logical array?
if I use `=SUM(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE)` it give 2

Now, Let the cell A1 is abcdea & I used `=IFERROR(MID(A1,ROW(A1:A11),1)=MID(A1,LEN(A1)+1-ROW(A1:A11),1),0)` and then checked by F9 it gives {TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;0;0;0;0;0}
now if I use `=SUM(IFERROR(MID(A1,ROW(A1:A11),1)=MID(A1,LEN(A1)+1-ROW(A1:A11),1),0))` it gives zero  , but I expected 2.
so is there any way to SUM logical arrays?
Thanks!
regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--` will convert the Boolean into their integer equivalents.
so `=SUM(--IFERROR(MID(A1,ROW(A1:A11),1)=MID(A1,LEN(A1)+1-ROW(A1:A11),1),0))` gives expected solution.

Answer (score 0):

Libreoffice: `--` will not work as indicated.

The problem comes from attempting math on boolean values.
In practice this is equal to TRUE+TRUE where the result cannot be more than a single TRUE. i.e. two true doesn't make double TRUE in boolean.

Ponder on `=(1=1)+(2=2)` if you didn't follow ^ that.

`=SUM( IF( MID(A1;ROW(A1:A11);1)=MID(A1;LEN(A1)+1-ROW(A1:A11);1) ;1;0) )`
should work in both Excel and anything else.

The same should be the case for:
`=SUM( IFERROR( (MID(A1;ROW(A1:A11);1)=MID(A1;LEN(A1)+1-ROW(A1:A11);1))*1 ;0) )`

*Note the `;`'s, replace these with `,` depending on your locale/region*

Comment: Hi Hannu, I can not understand how ';' works ?

Comment: Check "List separator" in Control panel, Regional settings. (I'm in Sweden, you will see `;` if you set Sweden as country ;-)